# python variable function definition

Tags: python, eval

First, please don't shoot me if this has already been asked - I have looked around but to no avail.

I have a python file (named `rpc.py`) containing many functions serving AJAX requests. For example:

```
def test(self, vars):
    return vars['id']

def test2(self, vars):
    return vars['id']+1
```

And it is called with a URL like:

```
rpc.py?fnc=test2&id=4
```

I want to call the function that matches the `'fnc'` query parameter and pass the whole query string into `'vars'`.

So something like the following "pseudocode" is what I am after:

```
vars = cgi.FieldStorage()
print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n"
print eval('vars["fnc"].value(vars)')
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Wow, this is quite possibly the most insecure thing ever. You can (easily I might add) pass arbitrary code to get executed on your server. Never ever use eval. Instead, find a sane way to do it

Comment: i appreciate your response but i was after a solution more than just an observation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```
getattr(server, vars["fnc"])(vars)
```

but I'd also suggest adding a prefix to the service names (e.g. "do_test") to avoid malicious code that would be able to call any of the methods of the server object simply by passing their names (including ones you think it shouldn't). In this case it would be

```
getattr(server, "do_" + vars["fnc"])(vars)
```

Comment: yeah i've heard bad stuff about eval which is why i don't want to use it (albeit i don't fully understand its evil ways), but what exactly is 'server'? i get error "NameError: name 'server' is not defined"

Comment: Your functions were accepting a `self` parameter, so I thought they were methods of a class and that you had a class instance serving requests. I called `server` the variable holding that class instance.

Comment: it works! here is my final code
class response:

 def do_test(self, v):
  return "test"+str(v['id'].value)

 def do_test2(self, v):
  return "test2"


if __name__ == "__main__":

 vars = cgi.FieldStorage()
 server = response()

 print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n"

 print getattr(server, "do_"+vars["fnc"].value)(vars)